# How to use socket.io to handle requests?

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io, httprequest

I am trying to use socket.io for handling requests between html page and http server I got **Cannot POST /**  **[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]**
the server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
console.log(__dirname);
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname+'/public/registration.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('registration',function(msg){
    console.log('user data'+ msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

html page like the following

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.4.js">
            var socket = io('http://localhost');
            console.log(socket);
            socket.emit('registration',"test");
      </script>

  </head>
  <body>
```

Comment: Your error `Cannot POST / [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]` implies a form submission or a POST ajax call, neither of which you show anything on your client side.  So that error is coming from some code you do not show.  We can't help you without seeing what code/HTML is leading to that particular error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install node,
2. Create a folder for your app,
3. Create package.json file:

   `{
     "name": "socket.io-test",
     "version": "0.0.1",
     "private": true,
     "scripts": {
        "start": "node server"
     },
     "dependencies": {
       "express": "~4.13.1",
       "socket.io": "^1.4.6"
     }
   }`
4. Run `npm install`,
5. Create server.js - your original code pasted here:

   ```
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();
   var http = require('http').Server(app);
   var io = require('socket.io')(http);
   console.log(__dirname);
   app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
   app.get('/', function(req, res){
     res.sendfile(__dirname+'/public/registration.html');
   });
   io.on('connection', function(socket){
       socket.on('registration',function(msg){
       console.log('user data'+ msg);
     });
   });

   http.listen(3000, function(){
     console.log('listening on *:3000');
   });
   ```
6. Create the `/public` folder in your working directory,
7. Create `/public/registration.html` file:

   `<html>
      <head>
         <script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
         <script>
               var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
               socket.on('connect', function() {
                 socket.emit('registration',"test");
                 document.getElementById('socket').innerHTML='connected';
               });
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>Testing socket.io with nodejs</h1>
       <h3 id="socket"></h3>
    </body>
   </html>`
8. Start the server with `node server` or `npm start`,
9. Go to `localhost:3000` in your browser

It will work

Comment: @Mohammed Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please edit these details in to your original question or we may not be able to help.